# Actively Monitor exe running when called

Tags: c#, dcmtk

I have a app I have been working on that just sends and receives dicom files using dcmtk. My current problem is that I need help trying to figure out a way to  monitor a exe actively when called. So once my code runs which spits out console output to a textbox. Im grabbing the last entry in that text box and if it is "I: Releasing Association" and storescu closes it will delete all the items in a folder(dicompath)

```
        startInfo2.ErrorDataReceived += proc_DataReceived;
        startInfo2.OutputDataReceived += proc_DataReceived;

        startInfo2.Start();
        startInfo2.BeginOutputReadLine();

        startInfo2.WaitForExit(10);
        //Thread.Sleep(1000);


        DeBug.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { DeBug.Text = finalpath; }));

        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("storescu-beta.exe");
        foreach (Process p in processes)
        {
            IntPtr pFoundWindow = p.MainWindowHandle;
            if (trig.Text == "I: Releasing Association")
            clearFolder(dicompath);clearFolder(dicompath);
        }
```

So far I have not be able to get any of this to work. It seems the output to the textbox is trying to look for the "I: releasing Association" before its there so I need to add somehow a wait until its done updating. each output to the textbox is one line of the console so at the very end it just has "I: releasing Association". 
As for the monitoring storescu-beta.exe Im at a loss because I dont know how to monitor for its running status actively when called.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: which part? Basically, want to monitor the running status of storescu-beta.exe, once it stops running and my textbox.text = a specific text.. do something.(ClearFolder).

Comment: Everything. _monitor a exe_; what exe? _when called_ who, what, where, when and/or how called? _spits out console output to a textbox_ console windows don't have textboxes _storescu closes it will delete all the items in a folder(dicompath)_ how is that relevant? _to the textbox is trying to look for_ textboxes have data, not code, so they can't "LOOK"

Comment: Im using the textbox to see what is at the end of the output from the console. Once the textbox = the value I want it will trigger an event. That event will see if a exe is running and if its not that will trigger another event. That event will delete the files froma folder.. not sure I can spell it out anymore. please dont troll my post. If you have a solution or something that is helpful post it, if not kick rocks. thx.

Comment: Note that the typical response in these situations is to edit the question instead of explaining in a comment. Note that my comment is very nice compared to some that you will get around here. Getting clarification is a critical requirement for providing useful answers. What I don't like is when I don't get an explanation for why I am voted down and such. Based on your last response, you won't be getting much help.